# Spinner implementation in css3

Tags: css, spinner

I am trying to implement spinner in css3. everything is working fine except white square displaying overlaying spinner circle. As displaying in below image. (Browser: Firefox 25.0.1)

[image]

**Css :-**

```
.spinner {
    height: 30px;
    width: 30px;
    margin: 0px auto;
    position: relative;
    -webkit-animation: rotation .6s infinite linear;
    -moz-animation: rotation .6s infinite linear;
    -o-animation: rotation .6s infinite linear;
    animation: rotation .6s infinite linear;
    border-left: 3px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, .15);
    border-right: 3px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, .15);
    border-bottom: 3px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, .15);
    border-top: 3px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, .8);
    border-radius: 100%;
}
@-webkit-keyframes rotation {
    from {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
    }
    to {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(359deg);
    }
}
@-moz-keyframes rotation {
    from {
    -moz-transform: rotate(0deg);
    }
    to {
    -moz-transform: rotate(359deg);
    }
}
@-o-keyframes rotation {
    from {
    -o-transform: rotate(0deg);
    }
    to {
    -o-transform: rotate(359deg);
    }
}
@keyframes rotation {
    from {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
    }
    to {
    transform: rotate(359deg);
    }
}
```

<kbd>[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tnZ69/)</kbd> <kbd>[My Browser Info](https://aboutmybrowser.com/a_4jhaCo)</kbd>

Comment: Tested on Opera 12 and IE 11, everything looks great, as it should...in which browser have you noticed this behavior?

Comment: I don't see the aforementioned "white square" in Chrome 31.0.1650.57.  What browser are you using?

Comment: Mine looks good in Chrome 31 and FF 25.0.1. Are you running any addons or any experimental settings?

Comment: Just run my fiddle example and look carefully. it will look like as image attached.

Comment: We did run it and look carefully. It's not showing up for us. Have you tried it yourself on a different computer?

Comment: Yes. I have checked it.facing problem in firefox

Comment: @ZachSaucier : Many thanks to point me right direction. After disable addons its working fine.